# routing not working in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like to use React Router but I can't seem to get it working. I'm new to React and I used React boilerplate to get things started.

Find below the code from App.js:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import Login from './Login.jsx';
  import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
  import './App.css';

  ReactDOM.render((
     <Router history={hashHistory}>
         <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
     </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Login.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="Login">
        <button className="LoginButton">S'inscrire</button>
        <button className="LoginButton">Se connecter</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

and the errors I have in the console:

[image: Error console]

What am i doing wrong? As far as I can tell, Login is a React Component so it should be rendered in App.js since it is exported as default and imported as such.

Comment: Can you try the following?
 import Router, { Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

Comment: I copy and paste your code ... and here it worked... Could you provide a github repo?

Comment: Thanks. I started by using https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate. I just created and edited these two files, I otherwise didn't change an other thing.